# Build Json from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, functional-programming

I'm trying to use typescript to build a json object from an array of objects like this one:[

```
[
  { attribute: 'a', modifier: 121 },
  { attribute: 'b', modifier: 67 },
  { attribute: 'c', modifier: 121 },
  { attribute: 'd', modifier: 67 } 
]
```

I would like to get something like:

```
{
  a:  121,
  b:  67,
  c:  121,
  d:  67  
}
```

But I just can't get my head around the high order functions to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `reduce` method which accepts as **parameter** a **callback** function.

Read more about [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b) method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b).

```js
let array=[
  { attribute: 'a', modifier: 121 },
  { attribute: 'b', modifier: 67 },
  { attribute: 'c', modifier: 121 },
  { attribute: 'd', modifier: 67 } 
];
let obj=array.reduce(function(obj,item){
  obj[item.attribute] = item.modifier;
  return obj;
},{});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) in combination with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var array = [{ attribute: 'a', modifier: 121 }, { attribute: 'b', modifier: 67 }, { attribute: 'c', modifier: 121 }, { attribute: 'd', modifier: 67 }],
    result = Object.assign(...array.map(o => ({ [o.attribute]: o.modifier })));

console.log(result);
```

With [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
var array = [{ attribute: 'a', modifier: 121 }, { attribute: 'b', modifier: 67 }, { attribute: 'c', modifier: 121 }, { attribute: 'd', modifier: 67 }],
    result = Object.assign(...array.map(({ attribute, modifier }) => ({ [attribute]: modifier })));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```js
var arr = [
  { attribute: 'a', modifier: 121 },
  { attribute: 'b', modifier: 67 },
  { attribute: 'c', modifier: 121 },
  { attribute: 'd', modifier: 67 } 
]
var map = {};
arr.forEach( function(item){ map[ item.attribute ] = item.modifier });
console.log( JSON.stringify( map, 0, 4 ) )
```